# how can i copy a div from external html file and save it into other html file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy an HTML `div` from external file and save it into other html file by clicking a button and using JavaScript:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container1">
      <p>text 1</p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
    
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container2">
      <p>text 2</p>
    </div>
    <button>Click here</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi salah, 
personally find it hard to understand, could you give this one a try, and then re-upload ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what http server and server side language are you running - this all needs to be done in server code

Comment: Why do you need this? Why can't you simply copy the div manually?

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```html
<!-- a.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page A</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="target"></div>
  <button onclick="loadElement('b.html', 'div#y', 'div#target')">Copy div#y from b.html</button>
  <script>
    async function loadElement(sourceFileName, sourceSelector, targetSelector) {
      // Load the whole <body> of the source HTML file
      const response = await fetch(sourceFileName);
      const text = await response.text();
      const i1 = text.indexOf("<body>");
      const i2 = text.indexOf("</body>");
      const bodyHTML = text.substring(i1 + "<body>".length, i2);

      // Add it to the target element
      const targetElement = document.body.querySelector(targetSelector);
      targetElement.innerHTML = bodyHTML;

      // Keep only the source element
      const sourceElement = targetElement.querySelector(sourceSelector);
      targetElement.innerHTML = "";
      targetElement.append(sourceElement);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The file to load the div from:

```html
<!-- b.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page B</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="x">Hello from b.html div#x!</div>
            <div id="y">Hello from b.html div#y!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="z">Hello from b.html div#z!</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested this by starting a Python web server on Windows (`py -m http.server`) from the folder of these files, and opening `http://localhost:8000/a.html` in Chrome. Clicking on the button loads the selected div from `b.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery can solve your problem.
If you want to get div(id = "DivA") content from sampleA.html into your current html div (id= "DivB"). Assume these 2 html files are under same path.

```
$( "#DivB" ).load( "sampleA.html #DivA" );
```